# How to create Associative array using IDictionary and mysql in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I was wondering something that should be looks like this:

```
[
    "row" => [
        "name" => "something here",
        "desc" => "something there"
    ],
    "row" => [
        "name" => "the name",
        "desc" => "the description"
    ],
];
```

How can I do that in C#? And anyways, the data is taken from `mysql` database.

I want it to be returned as above to be used somewhere else. Most of the basic tutorial and threads gave me a `console.writeline` technique which I don't need. Please help, here is my code example.

```
public IDictionary<string, string> Get(string query)
{
    if (this.OpenConnection())
    {
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                var querybuilder = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                querybuilder.Add(reader.GetName(i), reader.GetString(i));
            }

        }

        reader.Close();
        this.CloseConnection();

        return querybuilder;
    }

    return querybuilder;
}
```

Comment: What does the querybuilder dict contain as of now?

Comment: sorry, I misunderstand your question. It contain only ["key", "value"] right now. And I need it to be ["key" => "value"]

Comment: Is the key "row" always going to have the same value ? or is it just representative of being a differnet row ?

Comment: yes @AnuViswan , I planned it to be used in foreach statement, so it has to be static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like "Row" doesn't quite mean anything in this context.For iteration, you do not quite require it.

```
public List<IDictionary<string, string>> Get(string query)
{
    var list = new List<IDictionary<string, string>>();
    if (this.OpenConnection())
    {
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var querybuilder = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {

                querybuilder.Add(reader.GetName(i), reader.GetString(i));
            }
            list.Add(querybuilder);
        }

        reader.Close();
        this.CloseConnection();
    }

    return list;
}
```

You can now iterate as following

```
var result = Get(query);
foreach(var item in result)
{
  foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in item)
  {
     Debug.Write($"{entry.Key} = {entry.Value}");
  }
}
```

Comment: it gave me an error when I tried to `debug.writeLine()` the output.. `Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, string>' to 'string'`

Comment: it is a collection right ? You need to loop over and print it.... foreach(var item in result){ foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in item)
{
   Debug.WriteLine($"{entry.Key}={entry.Value}");
}

Comment: I still don't get it work.. no errors but it said The thread 0x4704 has exited with code 0 (0x0) now.

Comment: oooohh... my fault, I forgot to put `list.Add(querybuilder)` after the for loop. It works like a charm. Thank you my friend..